# Streaming Audio from User microphone to multiple users on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

Right now I am using Node.js to Javascript to take the microphone audio data from 1 user and to have other people listen to that user's mic audio via browser. I am trying to do this right now with socket.io. How can I achieve this? right now I can send messages but not audio or a simple audio file. It would be awesome if I can livestream the user's microphone audio. Any simple client/server code example would be so appreciated. I've been reading about this for hours and everything seems so confusing. **If the problem is too hard, I also have a wav file, but how can I send that?** Please help please!

Here is my current code.

Server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
    });
    response.write("WebSocket Start~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    response.end("");
}).listen(8080);

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function (client) {

    client.on('client-stream-request', function (data) {
        var stream = ss.createStream();
        var filename = __dirname + '/downloads/' + < YOURSONG.MP3 > ;
        ss(socket).emit('audio-stream', stream, {
            name: filename
        });
        fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
    });


    client.on('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Received message from client!', event);
        client.receive audio from user 1 browser mic ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
            client.emit('emitMessage', {
                hello: 'messgge received, wish you happy' + new
                Date().toString()
            });
    });
    client.on('disconnect', function () {
        // clearInterval(interval); 
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });
    client.send('hello, I am the server');
    client.send user 1 browser mic audio to everyone connected to the server ? ? ? ? ? ?
});
```

Here is my client code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <style>
        div {
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 2px solid pink;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        //创建Socket.IO实例，建立连接

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        var audio = document.getElementById('player');
        ss(socket).on('audio-stream', function (stream, data) {
            parts = [];
            stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                parts.push(chunk);
            });
            stream.on('end', function () {
                audio.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(parts));
                audio.play();
            });
        });

        // 添加一个连接监听器
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
        });

        // 添加一个连接监听器
        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += data + "<br />";

        });
        socket.on('emitMessage', function (data) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += data.hello + "<br />";

        });

        // 添加一个关闭连接的监听器
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('The client has disconnected!');
        });

        // 通过Socket发送一条消息到服务器
        function sendMessageToServer(message) {
            socket.send(message);
        }
        var date = new Date();
        var ms = "Time: " + date.toString() + "Today is a nice day, wish you happy";
        setInterval("sendMessageToServer(ms)", 1000);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```